# jQuery scrollTop in browser window in portrait mode

Tags: jquery

I'm debugging an issue which only occurs when my webapp was opened(!) on a monitor in portrait mode. 
Currently I've set my laptops screen to portrait and I'm struggling with the obscure handling of keyboard and trackpad.

The following line give me the correct result in landscape mode.

```
    var scrollPos = this.$(scrollTag).scrollTop();
```

When in portrait mode I get a value of 110 when the scrollbar is a the bottom. This seems a bit low.

How can I find out if the monitor is in portrait mode?
And how would I correctly retrieve the scrollTop position in portrait mode?

Comment: Get screen resolution in JS using screen object. (screen.height;
screen.width;)
And calculate if width is bigger than height. Something like that?

Comment: That should cover most screens. The second part on how to calculate the scroll position is bugging me most though..